# jQuery - how to find specific cell in a table using selectors?

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors, row, col

Given each cell has row, col attributes.
I've tried something like

```
$(#mytable tr td row=1 col=1)
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: do you mean `$(#mytable tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first-child` or `nth-child`. For example:

```
$("#mytable tr:first-child td:first-child")

$("#mytable tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)")
```